# Get jquery autocomplete input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, frontend

```
$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(doSomething);
    $(window).resize(doSomething);
});

function doSomething()
{
    var autocomplete = $(".ui-autocomplete:visible");
    // How can I get input DOM element of currently shown autocomplete there?
}
```

How can I get input DOM element of currently shown autocomplete if I am outside of the scope of autocomplete declaration?

Comment: I think jQuery Autocomplete class is something like ui-autocomplete-input

Comment: I cannot use ui-autocomplete-input class because there are many such inputs on the page

Comment: Do you mean the currently highlighted option or the input field itself?

Comment: @phpcoderx the input field itself

Comment: I'd suggest you use another tagging convention, but `$('.ui-autocomplete-input')` should do the job

Comment: why not use a global variable and set its value to the `id` of the current input inside the autocomplete function?

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
var currentAutocompleteTextbox = null; //global variable

$(textbox).focus(function () { currentAutocompleteTextbox = textbox; });
$(textbox).autocomplete({ ... });
```

Can anyone propose a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is unclear. 
If all you want is to get the last interacted autocomplete textbox your best bet is to use one of the autocomplete plugin events. Below is sample code which uses the focus event. The callback function will execute with the corresponding input textbox as context; therefore `this` will point to *that* textbox.

```
$(".language").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        focus: function(evt, ui){
            var txtbx = $(this).parent().prev().text();
            $('#result').html(txtbx + ' textbox last focused');
        }
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7SrBv/)